# Which Data Structure is most used in Solidity and which Data Structures beginner should focus at first?

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x

Ali here...

I am a newbie in Solidity and Ethereum programming. I am learning Solidity these days using free resources on Youtube. As the question above states, I want you guys to suggest me Data Structures algorithms to learn as a beginner in Solidity Programming!.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solidity is not a suitable language to learn algorithms. It is a language to write smart contracts. If you write a small to medium-sized smart contract. Thinking about data structure just makes you confused.

I guess what you actually want is the source to practice the Solidity algorithm and data structure. Consider https://www.codewars.com/trainer/setup and choose Solidity. Or maybe https://solidity-by-example.org.

Comment: So you mean that we won't require arrays and mapping while building any contract?

Comment: I have never said it in my answer. Why do you ask me about that? You ask about algorithms and data structure (not `Data Structures algorithm` you should fix your question)for beginners of Solidity. I share some sources. But in my opinion, they are not important in small to medium projects for beginner, `not important` and `not required` is two different terms.